# pyparsing: skip to the next token ignoring everything in between

Tags: python, pyparsing

I am trying to parse a log file that contains multiple entries with the following format:

```
ITEM_BEGIN item_name
  some_text
```

`some_text` may *optionally* contain an expression matched by `my_expr` anywhere within itself. I am only interested in `item_name` and `my_expr` (or `None` if it is missing). Ideally, what I want is a list of `(item_name, my_expr)` pairs. What is the best way to extract this information using pyparsing?

Comment: Can you give a bit more detail, please? So `some_text` might contain `(item_name, my expr)` pairs or only `my_expr`? And how often? Make a BNF or give examples of input and output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are not trying to define a parser for the entire input text, but only some pieces of it, look into using pyparsing's `searchString` or `scanString` methods - something along these lines:

```
import pyparsing as pp
ident = Word(alphas, alphanums+'_')
item_header = pp.Keyword("ITEM_BEGIN") + ident("name")
other_expr = ... whatever ...

search_expr = item_header | other_expr

found = {}
current_name = ''
for result in search_expr.searchString(input_text):
    result = result[0]
    if result[0] == "ITEM_BEGIN":
        print("found an item header with name {name}".format_map(result))
        current_name = result.name
        found[result.name] = []
    else:
        # found an other expr
        found[current_name].append(result.asList())
```

Comment: Paul, thanks very much for your answer. This works for me. I actually found a different way of dealing with this problem. I created a parser that looks for a chunk of text starting with ITEM_BEGIN and terminated by another ITEM_BEGIN and attached a ParseAction that calls my_expr.searchString() on the found text. The only problem is newlines are included as literal '\\n' - something I'm trying to fix at the moment.