# pyparsing: ignore any token that doesn't match

Tags: python, pyparsing

I have this file from a game that I'm trying to parse. Here is an excerpt:

```
    <stage> id: 50  #Survival Stage
            <phase> bound: 1500  # phase 0   bandit
                    music: bgm\stage4.wma
                    id: 122  x: 100  #milk  ratio: 1
                    id: 30 hp: 50  times: 1
                    id: 30 hp: 50  times: 1  ratio: 0.7
                    id: 30 hp: 50  times: 1  ratio: 0.3
            <phase_end>
    <stage_end>
```

The `#` denotes a comment, but only to human readers, not to the game's parser. The first two comments are to the end of the line, but the `ratio: 1` after `#milk` is not part of the comment, it actually counts. I think the game's parser ignores any tokens it can't understand. Is there a way to do this in pyparsing?

I tried using `parser.ignore(pp.Word(pp.printables))` but that makes it skip over *everything*. Here's my code so far:

```
import pyparsing as pp

txt = """
<stage> id: 50  #Survival Stage
        <phase> bound: 1500  # phase 0   bandit
                music: bgm\stage4.wma
                id: 122  x: 100  #milk  ratio: 1
                id: 30 hp: 50  times: 1
                id: 30 hp: 50  times: 1  ratio: 0.7
                id: 30 hp: 50  times: 1  ratio: 0.3
        <phase_end>
<stage_end>
"""

phase = pp.Literal('<phase>')
stage = pp.Literal('<stage>') + pp.Literal('id:') + pp.Word(pp.nums)('id') + pp.OneOrMore(phase)
parser = stage

parser.ignore(pp.Word(pp.printables))

print(parser.parseString(txt).dump())
```

Comment: Can you say what game this is?

Comment: possible duplicate : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43075547/pyparsing-skip-to-the-next-token-ignoring-everything-in-between

Comment: @user2357112 Little Fighter 2

Comment: @JoranBeasley The answer to that question doesn't work for me because I want to parse the whole file.

Comment: yeah you would parse each line ... or write a rule to ignore comment tokens

Comment: From the document I found online (http://lf2-global.com/article.asp?id=20#9) the '#' character denotes a comment, but it's not clear where the comment ends. As you describe, the first comments go to the end of the line. This is easily done in pyparsing with `parser.ignore(pp.pythonStyleComment)` I think that If you have data after a `#` sign, then that data is malformed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out in the stock game file only the `ratio:` keyword ever appears after a `#`, so I used that to define the end of a comment, like so:

```
parser.ignore(Suppress('#') + SkipTo(MatchFirst([FollowedBy('ratio:'), LineEnd()])))
```